# Unsupported endpoint type for uri telegram

Tags: java, apache-camel, telegram

So I try to use the telegram component in camel. I added the depency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-telegram</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And created a BotRoute.class

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class BotRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("telegram:bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                .bean(ChatBotLogic.class)
                .to("telegram:bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
}
```

But camel fails at creating the route with following error

```
ERROR Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: 
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[telegram:bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA... 
because of Failed to resolve endpoint: telegram://bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA due to: 
Unsupported endpoint type for uri telegram://bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, remaining bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

The camel-telegram depency got added to my external libary from maven, so it should know the telegram:bots uri.

**Edit**

So with the debugger I figured out, that camel works with the uri `telegram://bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` there are two `//` added to the uri between `telegram:type` thats my problem. Now I have to figure out where these two get added from.

Comment: So with the debugger I figured out, that camel works with the uri telegram://bots/123456789:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA there are two // added to the uri between telegram:type thats my problem. Now I have to figure out where these two get added from

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
"telegram:bots?authorizationToken=12345678:AAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhgsd5f"
```

as uri and it works now.